# Which Merc group is the best for the Aria T'Loak quests?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I'm trying to decide which group to help out,  Blue suns, Eclipse or the Blood Pack.  Which group is the best overall for help and supplies?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no reason to not simply help all three - every merc group you gain the help of shows up as part of the "Terminus Fleet" War Asset.

I've picked up all three, and the Terminus Fleet is listed at 200 strength.

Comment: Thank you I wasnt sure if I could do all three thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, you can help all of them and get all of them to join you as War Assets. I know that I have already helped two of them.

Answer (score 0):

You need all three Merc groups for war asset and they also work on billding the weapon that will allow you to kill the repairs or rebuild them

Comment: Welcome to [Gaming.SE].  Please see the [Help Center](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) for tips on writing good answers.  For example, your reply is difficult to understand and only restates information already given in previous answers.

Comment: OK I am sorry I'm new to this and I have completed mass effect 3   4-5 times already I was just saying what I knew that was all